# Simple Html.Actionlink question (MVC3)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-routing, html.actionlink

The Route:

```
            routes.MapRoute(
            "Items", // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new {controller = "Item", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional} // Parameter defaults
            );
```

The htmlhelper:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Chairs", "List", "Item", new {id="Chairs"}, null)
```

The link it generates:

```
http://localhost:57899/Item/List?id=Chairs
```

What I want it to show:

```
 http://localhost:57899/Item/List/Chairs
```

How to do that?

Comment: What's the signature on your `ItemController`'s `List` action?

Comment: @David Signature?`public ActionResult List(string id)
        {
            return View(_repository.GetItems(id));
        }`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using ActionLink what happens if you try the following?

```
@Html.RouteLink("Items", new { id = "Chairs" })
```

Answer (score 0):

You call Html.RouteLink (not Action Link) and map an additional route under your generic like this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
        "ChairsRoute", // Route name
        "Item/List/{id}", // URL with parameters
        new {controller = "Item", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional} // Parameter defaults
        );
```

when you call RouteLink, you'll simply pass that "ChairsRoute" name